# django - error adding database to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am struggling to deploy my app on heroku. Mainly due to database configuration.

This is the bottom of the settings.py file,

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config() }

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This is my local_settings.py file,

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(**file**))

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }  
}
```

I can run `heroku local web` successfuly.

But when I run , `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, it gives me error,

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I run, `heroku run python manage.py shell`,

And then run

```
>>> import dj_database_url
>>> dj_database_url.config()
```

I get the dictionary giving me the full information about the database.

Where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the settings from `local_settings.py` first, then change the `DATABASES` setting,

```
import dj_database_url
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass

DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config() }
```

You have defined a `DATABASES` variable in the file, but when you are importing the `local_settings.py`, your `DATABASES` configuration is being overridden by the development values. You should do the import first and then change the `DATABASES` option.

Personally, I'd suggest that you should keep a `base_settings.py` to contain every settings other than databases, then import the same into the `heroku_settings.py`, rather than importing the whole `local_settings`.

Keeping a `base_settings`, `development_settings`, `heroku_settings`(or production_settings) would make it easier to handle the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Your local_settings file should not be deployed. It is for local use only, hence the name. You should exclude it from your git repo.

Comment: why it shouldn't be deployed ?

Comment: Because it's for use *locally*. As the other answer said, it's overwriting the production db settings which removes the whole point of the dj_database_url stuff.